# Python Not Opening Image Files

Tags: python, image, directory, png

Code:

```
import turtle as trtl
wn = trtl.Screen()

wn.setup(width = 1.0, height = 1.0)
wn.bgpic("Underseav2_BG.png")
wn.mainloop()
```

Error Message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Natha\Desktop\ATCS Create Task\main_game.py", line 7, in <module>
    wn.bgpic("Underseav2_BG.png")
  File "C:\Users\Natha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\turtle.py", line 1482, in bgpic
    self._bgpics[picname] = self._image(picname)
  File "C:\Users\Natha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\turtle.py", line 478, in _image    return TK.PhotoImage(file=filename, master=self.cv)  File "C:\Users\Natha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 4093, in __init__
    Image.__init__(self, 'photo', name, cnf, master, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\Natha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 4038, in __init__
    self.tk.call(('image', 'create', imgtype, name,) + options)
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't open "Underseav2_BG.png": no such file or directory
```

This is the Code I wrote and the error message I got. I have the image file in the same folder (shown in this image here:[Code&Folder]

[image: 1]

as my code, yet Python says they are not in the same directory. What has happened here, and is there anything I can do to fix it?
Thanks!

Comment: There is indeed no PNG file with that name. The file is JPG, you try to open PNG file.

Comment: I just changed it to .jpg and it still does not work.

Comment: Make sure that the current working directory from which you run the code is the same as the one in which the code and images are located. I guess they are not the same.

Comment: Do you know how I can check that? I am not very well versed in VSC.

Comment: Try printing the current working directory where you script is running and where it expects to find your image `print(os.getcwd())`

Answer (score 0):

If you download the image from the Internet, make sure that its original format is png.

If you download the image as a jpg and modify it to png, I think this will not work.

https://pixabay.com/illustrations/optical-flare-png-5397752/
I downloaded an image from this site in png format, the code worked successfully.

Answer (score 0):

if you're using Mac, right click -> Quick Actions -> Convert Image -> Choose the Format to "PNG"

[image]